# UNREACHABLE executed! error while trying to generate PTX

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-clang, ptx

I am trying to generate PTX code for 'nbody' sample program's kernel (nbody_kernel.cu) using clang/LLVM version 3.2. The nbody CUDA program is available in Nvidia's SDK.

I am referring to https://github.com/jholewinski/llvm-ptx-samples project.

Following are my commands,

clang++ -O4 -S -I/usr/local/cuda/include -emit-llvm -target nvptx64 nbody_kernel.cu -o nbody_kernel.ll

opt -O3 -loop-unroll -unroll-allow-partial nbody_kernel.ll -o nbody_kernel.ll

llc nbody_kernel.ll -o nbody_kernel.ptx

After execution of the last command(llc) I get a UNREACHABLE executed! error with the following stack trace

```
UNREACHABLE executed!
0  libLLVM-3.2svn.so 0x00000033eb79fadf
1  libLLVM-3.2svn.so 0x00000033eb7a01d6
2  libpthread.so.0   0x0000003825a0f500
3  libc.so.6         0x0000003824e328a5 gsignal + 53
4  libc.so.6         0x0000003824e34085 abort + 373
5  libLLVM-3.2svn.so 0x00000033eb788320 llvm::llvm_unreachable_internal(char const*, char const*, unsigned int) + 336
6  libLLVM-3.2svn.so 0x00000033eb43dc37
7  libLLVM-3.2svn.so 0x00000033eb4411a0
8  libLLVM-3.2svn.so 0x00000033eb4422a5
9  libLLVM-3.2svn.so 0x00000033eb210d76 llvm::FPPassManager::doInitialization(llvm::Module&) + 54
10 libLLVM-3.2svn.so 0x00000033eb217ec7 llvm::FPPassManager::runOnModule(llvm::Module&) + 23
11 libLLVM-3.2svn.so 0x00000033eb217ac5 llvm::MPPassManager::runOnModule(llvm::Module&) + 389
12 libLLVM-3.2svn.so 0x00000033eb217c1b llvm::PassManagerImpl::run(llvm::Module&) + 107
13 llc               0x000000000040d157 main + 5415
14 libc.so.6         0x0000003824e1ecdd __libc_start_main + 253
15 llc               0x0000000000409a29
Stack dump:
0.  Program arguments: llc nbody_kernel.ll -o nbody_kernel.ptx 
1.  Running pass 'Function Pass Manager' on module 'nbody_kernel.ll'.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I replaced the global indexes like for e.g threadIdx.x  with __builtin_ptx_read_tid_x() and others.
There are no problems in generating LLVM IR (i.e .ll). The error pops up while trying to generate PTX from the IR using llc.

Any pointers on what might be going on here ?